Two-sided estimate for an elliptic PDE
Let $\Omega\subset\mathbb R^d$ be an open, connected, bounded domain with smooth boundary $\partial\Omega$. Consider the operator $\mathscr L$ with domain $C^{k+2,\alpha}_0(\bar\Omega)$ (i.e. $k+2$ times continuously differentiable functions vanishing at the boundary with $\alpha$-Hölder continuous $k+2^{nd}$ derivative) for some natural number $k$ and $\alpha\in(0,1)$ defined by
$$[\mathscr L u](x) := V(x)\cdot\nabla u(x) + \sum_{i=1}^d \sigma_i \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x_i^2} (x) $$
Where $V\in C^\infty(\bar\Omega)$ is a smooth $\mathbb R^d$-valued function and $\sigma_1,\ldots,\sigma_d>0$ are some positive constants. Associated to $\mathscr L$ is the PDE
$$\begin{cases}\mathscr Lu(x) &= -1 \ \text{ for } x\in\Omega\\
u(x) &= 0 \ \text{ for } x\in\partial\Omega\end{cases}\tag{PDE} $$
Let $u,u^*\in C^{k+2,\alpha}_0(\bar\Omega)$ be such that $u^*$ is the solution of $(PDE)$, and $u$ is arbitrary. I would like to get a two-sided estimate of the form
$$c\|u-u^*\|_{H^2(\Omega)}^2\le \|\mathscr L(u-u^*)\|_{L^2(\Omega)}^2\le C\|u-u^*\|_{H^2(\Omega)}^2 \tag 1$$
for some constants $c,C>0$ which may depend on $\Omega $ and the coefficients of $\mathscr L$.
By using some basic manipulations, it is pretty straightforward (see my work below) to get the upper bound
$$  \|\mathscr L(u-u^*)\|_{L^2(\Omega)}^2\le 2d\max\{\|V\|_{L^\infty(\Omega)}^2,\max_{i}\sigma_i^2\} \|u-u^*\|_{H^2(\Omega)}^2.$$
I expect that similar manipulations as the ones I did to get the above can be used to show that the desired lower bound holds with constant $ c \approx 2d\min\{\min_{x\in\bar\Omega}|V|^2,\min_{i}\sigma_i^2\}$, but so far I haven't been able to finish, hence my question : How to derive the lower bound of $(1)$ with an "explicit" constant $c$ ? If needed, I am okay with imposing further regularity conditions on the problem. Many thanks for your help !
P.S. : I found that theorem 15.2 in this paper by Agmon, Douglis and Nirenberg could possibly give me the lower bound I want (I still need to work through the assumptions and notations), but it seems like quite a big "hammer" for my relatively simple problem, and I would also like to have an explicit expression for the constant $c$, which their theorem does not provide as far as I can tell.

My work : By definition of the $L^2(\Omega)$ norm and expanding the square we get
$$\begin{align} \|\mathscr L(u-u^*)\|_{L^2(\Omega)}^2 &= \int_{\Omega} [ V\cdot\nabla (u-u^*)]^2 + \int_\Omega\left[\sum_{i=1}^d \sigma_i \frac{\partial^2 [u-u^*]}{\partial x_i^2} \right]^2\\
&+2\int_\Omega [ V\cdot\nabla (u-u^*)]\cdot\left[\sum_{i=1}^d \sigma_i \frac{\partial^2 [u-u^*]}{\partial x_i^2} \right]\\
&\le \tilde C\left( \|\text{div}(u-u^*)\|^2_{L^2(\Omega)} +  \|\Delta(u-u^*)\|^2_{L^2(\Omega)}\right)\\
&\le \tilde C d \|u-u^*\|^2_{H^2(\Omega)},
\end{align} $$
Where the first inequality holds with $\tilde C := 2\max\{\|V\|_{L^\infty(\Omega)}^2,\max_{i}\sigma_i^2\} $ by applying "Peter-Paul inequality", and the second inequality is a result of standard estimates such as this or this.
Now for the lower bound I'm quite stuck, I think that the Poincaré inequality can take care of the first two summands but I don't know how to handle the product of the divergence with the Laplacian. I have been playing with some vector calculus identities for a while now but nothing good came out of my attempts so far...
